# useHistory()'s block method in react-router-dom returns a different type than expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, routes, react-router

I jsut came across this issue out of the blue and it's stumping me. I'm using react-router-dom and accessing the useHistory hook.

```
const history = useHistory();

history.block((tx) => {
    console.log(tx)
    return true;
})
```

"tx" is supposed to be a type of "Transition<H.LocationState>", which possesses the "action" and "location" properties. However, console logging "tx" shows that tx is the following:

```
{pathname: "/memberships/add", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "1wlr2w"}
```

This seems to be the location in "tx". However, as I'm using TypeScript, this prevents me from accessing "tx" directly. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/blocking-transitions.md), this should be working in my example above, as the blocking function activates correctly upon changing routes (the console.log is called each time and no erros occur). I can work around this, but am wondering what could be the underlying issue here or if I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is weird but it seems like there are two very different definitions for the `History.block` method depending on whether it comes from [@types/history](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5454930b2034878b7cf0d749a1272a5e37f41bfa/types/history/index.d.ts#L22) or [from the package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/ef40006b921c57ef03ae5e5ec6376072095485b1/packages/history/index.ts#L317) directly.